# Simplifying Complex Fractions: Why Am I Wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently encountered the complex fraction 
$$x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x}}}}$$

I am confused because the correct result was very different from the one I get from my method. I took the reciprocal of each fraction in the denominator. The reciprocal of $$x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x}}$$ is $2x+1/x$. I did this for all the other terms until I got $4x+1/x$.

---

Why is this wrong? Can someone please explain to me why I can't take reciprocals like this, and simplify the fraction like this? Can you also do this as simply as possible, because I am still a beginner and will not understand complicated math notation?

Comment: Work it from the bottom. First, combine $x+\frac{1}{x}$. Then take the reciprocal of that result. Then sum $x$ plus the result just obtained, and combine into a new fraction. Continue the process.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\frac1{a+b}=\frac1a+\frac1b$.

Comment: Please do not use images for equations. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown. Can you elaborate on how I am making that assumption, and why it is causing me to get the wrong answer?

Comment: It is hard for me to explain what you did wrong since I do not understand what you did. Just how did you "reciprocal" that expression and get the next expression? I can think of several things you may mean--which do you mean? Show your intermediate steps, please.

Comment: @EthanChan Making that elementary blunder is the only way I can see of going from $x+\frac1{x+\frac1x}$ to $2x+\frac1x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $x + \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x^2 + 1}{x}$. Starting from the bottom, we get:

$$x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}}} = x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{\frac{x^2 + 1}{x}}}} = x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}}} = x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{\frac{x^3 + 2x}{x^2 + 1}}}$$

$$= x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 2x}}= x + \frac{1}{\frac{x^4 + 3x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 2x}} = x + \frac{x^3 + 2x}{x^4 + 3x^2 + 1} = \frac{x^5 + 4x^3 + 3x}{x^4 + 3x^2 + 1}$$

Comment: Okay, thanks. But what I want to know more is why is my method wrong? Where exactly have I gone wrong?

Comment: @EthanChan It is hard to determine where you went wrong, since you did not explain how you "reciprocaled" the expression. Can you elaborate on this in your question?